# Is the stackoverflow community a scale-free or a small world network?

Tags: algorithm, graph, social-networking

I am a graph/network enthusiast and this just for my curiosity :)

I am trying to model the StackOverflow community as a graph/network.  Assume that the people in the SO community are nodes and that the answers given to any of the question establishes a relationship between these nodes.  The relationship can be assumed to be directed(link from answer -> question) or undirected.  The graph could be weighted and that the weights of the nodes could represented number of vote-ups/downs (normalized on the scale of 0 to 1).

What kind of graph/network does one end up with at any given snapshot of time? Is it scale-free? Is it a small-world?  The graph is continuously evolving over a period of time and i would like to understand its structure and dynamics.

Is there a way where can i retrieve this relationship data from - may be SO APIs or some one from SO can help me out with (sample) data?

Clarification edit:
Scale-free network: A network whose degree distribution asymptotically follows a power law Small-world: A network that has sub-networks characterized by presence of connections between almost any two nodes within them and most pairs of nodes are connected by at least one short path.

Comment: I am not the author of this question.  I fixed a typo, and now my mugs up there as if the question were mine.  It is not.

Comment: when did edit history disappear?

Comment: What do you want to say with "scale-free" and "small world"? I'm pretty sure I misunderstood you. :)

Comment: It may be because the edits were too close to each other, and they were rolled into a single revision.

Comment: Scale-free network: A network whose degree distribution asymptotically follows a power law

Small-world: A network that has sub-networks characterized by presence of connections between almost any two nodes within them and most pairs of nodes are connected by at least one short path.

Comment: I added this information into your question.

Answer (score 2):

To the second part of your question:

> Is there a way where can i retrieve
>   this relationship data from - may be
>   SO APIs or some one from SO can help
>   me out with (sample) data?

Try these questions instead. There are a lot of plans to implement an API to access SO data. Some things are in change, but there are possibilities to screen-scrape the data or access them via JSON (afaik).

- [Is there a guide to accessing StackOverflow data programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282179/is-there-a-guide-to-accessing-stackoverflow-data-programmatically)
- [What would you want to see in a StackOverflow API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350248/what-would-you-want-to-see-in-a-stackoverflow-api)
- [Are there plans for a StackOverflow API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231847/are-there-plans-for-a-stackoverflow-api)

Try it out. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

> What kind of graph/network does one end up with at any given snapshot of time? Is it scale-free? Is it a small-world? The graph is continuously evolving over a period of time and i would like to understand its structure and dynamics.

It takes only a few links between remote clusters to turn a random network into a small world one, so it's quite likely to be small world.

As to whether it's scale free, that would require there to be a few posters with lots of answers and many with only one or two. I seem to recall Jeff saying that there were lots with only one question in one of the pod-casts; you might be better off asking the question there rather than here, as he will have the data.